# Anyone else had issues using an Azure-key-vault-connected pipeline variable group for an "Invoke Azure Function" pipeline check?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, cicd

I am configuring an Azure DevOps pipeline environment check of type "Invoke Azure Function". I am using a pipeline variable group in order to reference the function key value as a variable. The variable group has been created from a connected key vault in Azure. When I run the pipeline to trigger the check function, it returns a 401 and I can see from the function logs (no output at all) and the pipeline "response:0" that the function was not invoked. The function key is not getting passed to the function and the call is denied. I further tested this theory by hard coding the function key into the set-up form, instead of using a variable, and the function triggered and ran as expected.

Further details:

- When the function is triggered from Postman with the URI and function key, it also works as expected.
- I have triple checked that the value of the secret in the key vault is the same as the function key and the status is enabled.
- I have connected the correct key vault with the correct variable group to the correct pipeline check and there are no obvious errors or warnings.
- The DevOps identity and the Function App itself have GET and LIST access policies on everything in the connected key vault.
- I created a new repo and simple pipeline to test access to the key vault secrets and I was able to access the key vault and return values.
- All pipelines have been allowed permissions to use this pipeline check resource and the variable group.

Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution?   Other testing ideas also welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:  I have attached the pipeline check configuration, 401 error and the simple pipeline I created in the same project to test connection to the Azure key vault.
[Invoke Azure Function Config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc8xo.jpg)[Invoke Azure Function Config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mNWQ.jpg)
[401 error when pipeline check tries to trigger the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIWws.jpg)   [pipeline used in separate repo to test DevOps access to the key vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiN9o.jpg)

Edit 2 (In response to the bot asking for ways to reproduce the error)

Create:

- An Azure key vault with a secret. Set it up with access policies, not
  RBAC.
- An httptrigger Azure function. (Template:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal) Keep the URI and function key handy.
- A pipeline environment in DevOps.
- A pipeline that will deploy through the environment. (Template:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser)
- A variable group, linked to the Azure key vault that contains the
  secret.

Your DevOps identity and Function will need GET and LIST permissions on secrets to access the azure key vault.

Set up a pipeline check "Invoke Azure Function" through the "Approvals and checks" tab on the pipeline environment page.

- You will need the function URI and will add the function key as
  a variable from the linked variable group.  (The linked variable
  group is added in the control options area.)
- Set your method, leave the headers as default, query params empty.
- Set the function as APIResponse and leave the success criteria blank,
  if using the default httptrigger function.

The function working and pipeline code is irrelevant. The issue is: I cannot seem to trigger the function using a variable group linked to an azure key vault.  A function key hard coded into the form triggers the function, but not the variable in the form $(myVariable).

Comment: Testing from my side, there isn't any issue. Would you please share a screenshot of your Invoke Azure Function configuration and a screenshot of the 401 error? At the same time, please share the yaml of your pipeline.

Comment: I have attached 4 screenshots in the original post as an edit at the bottom.  thanks :) @ZiyangLiu-MSFT

Comment: Is your key vault using Key Vault Access Policies or Azure RBAC? Key Vaults using Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) are not supported. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault

Comment: Thanks @AdamVincent.  I am using access policies.  The DevOps identity and the Function App have GET and LIST access to the key vault for keys, secrets and certificates.  I have tested accessing both the key vault and the DevOps variable group connected to the key vault via a separate pipeline and this returns the correct value in both cases.  So I know the values from the key vault are in my variable group and should be accessible also to pipeline checks.

Comment: I don't see an issue here. The only suggestion I have is to run the pipeline again with "Enable System Diagnostics" checkbox next to the run button and see if you can find something else.  I may try and repro this if I can find some time.

Comment: @AdamVincent No new info from this.  The pipeline is just stuck in the queue as it waits for a check that will never pass.  Let me know if discover anything from your testing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Secret variable from Azure Key Vault(Variable Group).

[image]

I am afraid that Invoke function App task doesn't support using the secret from Azure Key Vault Variable group.

When we use the Azure Key Vault Variable in Agent job, it will add step to download the key vault first, then we can use it in Agent job.

[image]

But the Invoke Function App task is using Agentless job, it doesn't support downloading the Azure Key Vault secret. We are not able to using Azure Key Vault directly without downloading it.

So it doesn't support using the Azure Key Vault Secret.

For a workaround, you can directly define the Function Key as secret variable in Variable group.

For example:

[image]

Then we can use the secret variable in Invoke Function App task.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: seems like the MS docs could use some improvements regarding agentless jobs limitations. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops